# use of angular multiselect dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I am using ngDropdownMultiselect directive in angular.
Here is the tag i have used

```
 <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" ng-options="truck for truck in widget.filteredTrucks" ng-model="truck.selected"></div>
```

the output i am getting for this is

[image]

and when i click on it it throws the error saying `_ is not defined`
I have tried few things but not able to solve. help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: from doc **Note: Make sure to add lodash.js to your project, and make sure you use the regulate version of Lodash (NOT lodash.underscore or lodash.compat** pay attention to what your libs require

Comment: @OvidiuDolha I have loaded lodash.js using npm.

Comment: but is it available when the app runs (e.g. is the script loaded in your html)?

Comment: DropdownMultiselect.directive.js this the js file and yes it is getting loaded.

Comment: i meant that lodash.js should be loaded before angular and the rest of the scripts, is that the case?

Comment: no its not getting load

Comment: although i did npm install -g lodash

Comment: That doesn't help because that just installs it as a locally installed global tool (i.e. accessible across your projects while developing and in this context quite useless). You need to have it loaded on your "browser" when running the app. So you need to add a <script> to ref the library in your application (which starts from the index.html)

Comment: no no i meant i have included it in my node file.   var _ = require('lodash');

Comment: your node file (most likely) is not running the browser, where your angular app is executed... perhaps i'm missing something but post more details regarding your app setup, otherwise i'm just guessing here

Comment: oh i am sorry . i have a js file on my client side in which i have loaded the lodash